I changed the fuel pump on my F350 Ford. Now it won't start and receiving code 1DTC
I replaced fuel pump on my 2005 Ford F350 gas engine. Now it won't start and receiving code 1DTC.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! "1DTC" is not a code I'd expect from the ODBII system. Where are you getting that information from? Something you can do is to check that both the electrical connector at the tank is fully seated and that any ground is firmly attached (at the tank).

What engine is actually in it? Do you hear the fuel pump run for 2 seconds when the ignition switch is turned on?

Did you replace the fuel pump because logic said that the old pump was bad? Or because the old pump was tested and diagnosed as bad? If it was just assumed bad but not tested, some other failure, such as a blown fuse or a corroded connector, may have been the real culprit. If so, that other problem still exists and the new pump won't run either.
